# How to load a dataset from my google drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

This is the code that I wrote on google colab. However, after executing it gave an error.
Code:

```py
img_width =500
img_height = 500
X=[]
for i in tqdm(range(data.shape[0])):
  path= '/content/drive/My Drive/DData/img' + data['id'][i] + '.png'
  img= image.load_img(path, target_size=(img_width, img_height, 3))
  img = image.img_to_array(img)
  img = img/255.0
  X.append(img)
  X= np.array(X)
```

This is the Error:

```py
Error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-1aa91a1867f4> in <module>()
3 X=[]
4 for i in tqdm(range(data.shape[0])):
----> 5   path= '/content/drive/My Drive/DData/img' + data['id'][i] + '.png'
6   img= image.load_img(path, target_size=(img_width, img_height, 3))
7   img = image.img_to_array(img)
TypeError: must be str, not numpy.int64**
```

Comment: what is the contents of ```data['id'][i]```?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you store in `data['id']` but my guess is that it is an array of numbers which you cannot concat with strings. So one way should be to convert it to string:

```py
path= '/content/drive/My Drive/DData/img' + str(data['id'][i]) + '.png'
```

And another thing will not work in your code.
`X= np.array(X)` makes it into a `numpy` array which is not mutable, you will not be able to append anything to it in the next iteration.

Comment: I assigned numbers to my "id"

Comment: So does my answer answer your question? You have to convert it to string to make it work.